# Can Quicksight support Multi tenancy using different databases with the same datasets and dashboards?

Tags: multi-tenant, amazon-quicksight

We hold unique customer data on individual Redshift database and want each of these customers to use a common set of dashboards in Amazon Quicksight for our embedded SAAS application. If it did work we would want to change the database name for each group of customer users so they would only see their data.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: what is your driver for using different databases? why not use one database but with a column indicating the customer on each table?

Comment: The database driver is Redshift native. We already have all of the content in unique DBs, so not an easy or viable talk changing the database hierarchy

Comment: I do not mean the database driver - i mean what is the reason? is it security? is it performance? is it to allow charging back? - i need to know this to construct an answer

Comment: Security, many of our customers are competitors of each other

Answer (score 2):

I'm also currently researching this topic. From what I understood is that this can be achieved checkout the [Blog post from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-multi-tenant-analytics-in-applications-with-amazon-quicksight/) and [here](https://learnquicksight.workshop.aws/en/dashboard-embedding.html)

What we might do is that we will create a template from an analysis and generate a dashboard with different filters/datasets for each customer.
We then assign the dashboardId to the customer.
When the customer access our platform and wants to checkout the embedded dashboard our Frontend will request the Dashboard URL from a service of ours. This service knows which user and therefore which tenant requested the URL and will look for the assigned dashboardId. With the dashboardId our service will use the aws sdk to get a signed embed dashboard url. This url will be passed back to our Frontend. The frontend will then use the quicksight javascript sdk with the embed URL to render the specific dashboard.

What we have to do is:

- Have process to create a dashboard from the template when a tenant is created
- Have a data store that holds the dashboardid and the tenantid
- Have a process how we can mass replace the dashboardid in case we update our template.

Not sure if this is the right way..but this is where we are at right now. The benefits are we do not have to use quicksight users or use IAM federated users.

Comment: We have come to the same conclusion, with support from AWS, and ended up building an environment, in pilot now. The users are passed to different dashboards based on their authentication and the mapping we have built to match them to the appropriate underlying redshift databases. Not the simplest thing to implement but it is logical with the API.

Answer (score 0):

Within QuickSight, if you have multiple connections to different redshift clusters the only way to change the connection used within an analysis or dashboard is manually.

If your driver for splitting customers to separate Redshift databases is due to security and privacy, then you should careful not to break this security design by using a just a single quicksight dashboard to access all of them.

Instead you should consider :

- Best, most secure : use multiple AWS accounts, one for each client,
  each with their own QuickSight instance.
- Much less secure, but cheaper: within one quicksight account create
  separate analysis & dashboards for each customer